# How to get from Kigali to Malawi overland by public transport?

Tags: public-transport, road-trips, tanzania, malawi

I plan to travel from Kigali to Blantyre, Malawi in May next year.

I am wondering how it is to travel overland by public transport in Tanzania. In particular, how are the roads: bumpy and vehicles are slow, or well maintained? How many days will it take?

Answer (score 1):

There are two main different routes between the cities all of which pass through Malawi and Tanzania/Zambia

If you use the more popular Tanzania route passing over long stretches of B6    expect stretches to be Paved/Unpaved and thus bumpiness and traffic is inevitable on portions of your journey. A straight trip will take about 33 hours however with expected breaks from boarding different buses, expect a little under three days.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_in_Tanzania

Enjoy